# Polynomial degree

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Consider this equation: $9(x-0.4)^4+2$. I just want to confirm that this is a 4th degree polynomial.

Comment: What leads you to think that it is or that it isn't?

Comment: I am about 98% sure that it would be a 4th degree polynomial because it is raised to the 4th power. I just didn't know if the parentheses would change anything.

Comment: The [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) guarantees that the parentheses do not change anything. The degree of $(a+x)^n$ is $n$.

Answer (score 2):

We can just do it by brute force:
$$ 9\left(x-\frac{2}{5}\right)^4 + 2 = 9x^4 - \frac{72}{5}x^3 + \frac{216}{25}x^2 - \frac{288}{125}x + \frac{1394}{625}
$$
or, you can notice that raising a polynomial of order $m$ to exponent $n$ yields a polynomial of degree $mn$. It can be shown rigorously using the Binomial Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , degree of a polynomial is the highest degree of its terms. In this case, it is indeed 4

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. In general, a function of the form

$f(x) = a(x-b)^n + c$ where $n\geq1$ and $a \neq 0$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. This can be verified with the binomial theorem.

Comment: Thank you. And coefficients would be -0.4 and 2, right?

Comment: @user328399 No. The leading coefficient would be $9$

Comment: I meant to say constant, sorry mate. But, -0.4 isn't a constant?

Comment: @user328399 No, the constant would be something else. Try expanding it for youself!

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I think OP is asking if in their case $a=9$, $b=0.4$, $c=2$, in which case they're correct

Comment: Also look at Henry's expansion for coefficients

Comment: @leibnewtz True, but you can't really go wrong with giving a more general solution.

Comment: @leibnewtz Yes, a(the leading coefficient) = 9 b( moves it left or right)=0.4 and c( up or down)= 2 with this in mind, I would believe that 0.4 is a constant

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I definitely think your solution is a good one, sometimes it helps to see things as a special case of something more general. But I just felt there was a miscommunication occurring that needed to be clarified

Comment: @user328399 You're right, $0.4$ is a constant. In general any single element of a field (in your case the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$) is termed a constant when working in the polynomial ring over that field (in your case $\mathbb{R}[x]$).